# Change the sign of each local minimum in a binary file

Tags: java

bin file that contains an array of numbers:

```
new int[] {12, 6, 7, 1, 5, 15, 6, 4, 1, 15, 5}
```

There is a method (not working), which in a series of searches for a local minimum, and changes its sign to the opposite:

```
private static void doWork() {
    try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw")) {
        int n = (int)raf.length() / Integer.BYTES; // Кол-во
        int prevValue = raf.readInt(); // пред. элемент.

        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            // текущий элемент.
            int value = raf.readInt();
            // позиция текущего элемента
            long pos = raf.getFilePointer();
            // следующий элемент.
            int nextValue = raf.readInt();

            if (value < prevValue && value < nextValue) {
                raf.seek(pos);
                raf.writeInt(-value);
            }
        } // for i
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} // doWork
```

But it is not working properly: changes only once to the opposite sign and then with before. with up to a local minimum. Where am I screwed? (

Comment: First, language ! ;) Could you show the input/output of this file ? I am a bit concerned about this `readInt` done twice in the loop (seems to compare values by pair) then the use of `getFilePointer`. Could you be a bit more specific on this algorithm ? Using debugger would confirm that you are reading the file as you expect

Comment: What is your expected output? `{ 12, 6, 7, -1, 5, 15, 6, 4, -1, 15, 5 }`?

Comment: PS : `prevValue` is never updated, so you are actually doing `firstValue > value < nextValue`